# How to test the function after .then()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to write the unit test for a function.
Here is the code:

```
  const show = () => {
    SheetManager.hide('Screen1')
      .then(() => {
        SheetManager.show('Screen2', {
          payload: {
            preSheet: id,
          },
        });
      });
  };
```

The test code is like:

```
    jest.spyOn(SheetManager, 'hide').mockImplementation(() => {});
    jest.spyOn(SheetManager, 'show').mockImplementation(() => {});
    await waitFor(() => expect(SheetManager.hide).toBeCalledTimes(1));
    await waitFor(() => expect(SheetManager.hide).toBeCalledWith('Screen1'));

    // await waitFor(() => expect(SheetManager.show).toBeCalledTimes(1));
    // await waitFor(() => expect(SheetManager.show).toBeCalledWith('Screen2'));
```

The problem is the two commented line of test code of show function do not work. I think it's because the .then(), so the show function is called inside hide function.
So how should I change the code to make it work?

Look forward to your suggestion!

Comment: Can `show` be `async`? This avoids a lot of the nesting mess.

Comment: ... or even simply return the `hide()` promise so consumers can wait for it

Comment: @Phil Hi, could you please explain in more details about how to return the hide() promise? Thank you!

Comment: You put `return` before `SheetManager.hide('Screen1')`. Then you can more easily [test your asynchronous code](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)

Comment: I'd say the reason that `show` isn't detected as being called is that you've mocked the implementation of `hide`. There's no point mocking the thing you want to test